# pcap - does not work on specific interface

Tags: pcap, tcpdump

I have used pcap library used in my application. It was working previously.

I have not done any changes to my code, but fails to capture the packets only on specific interface "eth0". But for other interfaces like eth1 and wlan0 it works as expected.

Output of Ifconfig command is :

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.1.14.128  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.1.14.255
        inet6 fe80::5642:49ff:fee1:3a03  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 54:42:49:e1:3a:03  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 476  bytes 53618 (52.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 365  bytes 61306 (59.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 18  

eth1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::280:c8ff:fe3c:fe04  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:80:c8:3c:fe:04  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 34500  bytes 48274193 (46.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 1732834 (1.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 16436
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 10775  bytes 1170782 (1.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10775  bytes 1170782 (1.1 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 134.96.174.7  netmask 255.255.248.0  broadcast 134.96.175.255
        inet6 fe80::226:c7ff:fe9d:1f00  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:26:c7:9d:1f:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 981018  bytes 1250676710 (1.1 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 248507  bytes 31718095 (30.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Are these flag Id's(same for all) have anything to do with my problem .?

Best 
yash

Answer (score 0):

The driver of your interface will need to support putting the iface into [promiscous mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode) to collect packets that are not directly addressed to your NIC.

Comment: Thanks .. But I am doing it with sudo priviliges .. Also , it works for other interfaces.

Comment: What do priviledges have to with the driver of the interfaces support to caputre packets? Please read what i wrote.

Comment: Well I do understand the promiscuous mode operation . But I have already handled it in my code .
<code>
  descr = pcap_open_live(device1, MAXBYTES2CAPTURE, 0, -1, errbuf);
     if(descr == NULL)
       { printf("pcap_open_live(): %s\n",errbuf); }<\code>